# "Value of type 'DismissAction' has no member 'wrappedValue'" in Xcode of SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, environment-variables, swiftui-navigationlink

I got this error when try to run my code

=> "Value of type 'DismissAction' has no member 'wrappedValue'"

i was trying to learn to how go back to previous root without using back button of navigation bar because i planned to remove it but when i tried my code it doesn't run.

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) var presentationMode

    var body: some View{

        Button("dismiss"){
            presentationMode.self.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        .background(Color.teal)
        .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
  }
```

thank you

Comment: Must remove wrapped value there to work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `presentationMode.self.wrappedValue.dismiss()`, you have to declare your **@Enviroment** as `@Environment(\.presentationMode)`.

This error occurred because you are using the wrong type of **dismiss()**.

Also, you could achieve this dismissing in a simpler way by using `(\.dismiss)` type instead:

```
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss //modified
  var body: some View {
    Button("dismiss") {
        dismiss() //modified
    }
  }
```